# If ${\bf v},{\bf w}\in\mathbb R^n$, $\lVert{\bf v}+{\bf w}\rVert=\lVert{\bf v}\rVert+\lVert{\bf w}\rVert$, what can you say about $\bf v$ and $\bf w$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

What can you say about ${\bf v}$ and ${\bf w}$ if they are both nonzero and $\lVert{\bf v}+{\bf w}\rVert = \lVert{\bf v}\rVert + \lVert{\bf w}\rVert$?
Where ${\bf v},{\bf w} \in\mathbb R^n$

I cannot use ${\bf v}\cdot{\bf w} = \lVert{\bf v}\rVert\lVert{\bf w}\rVert\cos(\theta)$.

But, I can use ${\bf v},{\bf w}\in\mathbb R^n$ are said to be orthogonal if ${\bf v}\cdot{\bf w} = 0$.

Previously in the same question I have shown the following:

- $|{\bf v}\cdot{\bf w}| ≤ \lVert{\bf v}\rVert \lVert{\bf w}\rVert$
- $\lVert{\bf v} +{\bf w}\rVert\leq\lVert{\bf v}\rVert + \lVert{\bf w}\rVert $
- Assuming $\lVert{\bf v}\rVert = 2$ and $\lVert{\bf w}\rVert = 3$, $1 ≤ \lVert{\bf v} −{\bf w}\rVert\leq5$

So all of this stuff can be used!

As you can tell, I know the answer is that ${\bf v}$ and ${\bf w}$ are orthogonal (I think) but I'm really struggling to show this with these limitations, any help, hints or tips would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit yout question using Math formattation because this is unreadable. Thanks.

Comment: If $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are nonzero and orthogonal, then Pythagoras shows that $||\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w}|| < ||\mathbf{v}|| + ||\mathbf{w}||$.  You want to know when "equality occurs" in the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Comment: The vectors will not be orthogonal but aligned !

Comment: If $\lVert{\bf v}+{\bf w}\rVert=\lVert{\bf v}\rVert+\lVert{\bf w}\rVert$, then the magnitude (length) of the sum is the same as the sum of the magnitudes. Sketch some pictures, when does this occur? Always? Orthogonal? Parallel?

Comment: Thank you all so much - and sorry about the formatting, I've never had to type out maths before! So I understand now that it means they are parallel in the same direction - makes sense. And... I can show this by going back to the Cauchy-Schwartz and showing that equality occurs there when u and v are parallel (I'm assuming) as that's how I derived the Triangle inequality in this question

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Squaring the equation results in $$\langle v+w,v+w\rangle=\|v+w\|^2=(\|v\|+\|w\|)^2$$
or
$$
\langle v,w\rangle=\|v\|\|w\|.
$$